# How to parse a number with a decimal regardless of the language setting

Tags: parsing, localization, language-features, double

I am programming in C#.NET. I have a string that contains a number with a period as a decimal. How can I correctly parse that into a a double regardless of the localization/language settings. The string value will always be the same.

I think I need to use the `double.Parse(string s, IFormatProvider i)` overload of parse but I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `IFormatProvider` parameter, pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. It's in the `System.Globalization` namespace.

Comment: is InvariantCulture better than the other solution that I found below?

Comment: I'm not in the US, so for me the US culture isn't suitable in general. In this case -- parsing a double -- the US culture and the invariant culture will do the same thing.

Comment: @Jordan: InvariantCulture clearly communicates that you are parsing interchangeable format. And of course double.Parse(someString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); is shorter than your example (yeah, I know... ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

What about this...

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
myDouble= double.Parse("32.2", ci.NumberFormat);
```